# Renders that dont´look ok

Tags: rendering, texturing, lighting

I tried several render tutorials, even using profesional textures taken from texture webs, and doing what they say, and my renders never look ok, never reflect the material I see in the properties window. Does anybody have an idea of why? I have "render cycles" on, have connected all the nodes between them, have enough light.... I´ve never managed to get a render that works yet. Thanks for the help

[image: render does not work]

Comment: Have you unwrapped your models? It looks like you haven't.

Comment: You need to unwrap your model 1st. Hit "Tab" to enter edit mode then "U" to unwrap and choose one of the options (probably sphere in this case.)

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. It was part of the solution. I had no done the unwrapt. Anyway the looks are still not good. I´ll keep on trying ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try to recalculate the normals of the mesh you have applied the material onto. If that doesn't work, try inverting the normal map by making the strength of the normal map negative (-1.000)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I tried and unfortunatelly this didn´t work